# react storybook Apollo client mock useLazyQuery response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, mocking, storybook

I am trying to mock useLazyQuery hook response from Apollo client in storybooks. It works fine if we try to mock the query following the official docs but could not find a way to mock useLazyQuery response

Comment: This needs more detail. Please show the mock code you have so far.

Comment: @MichelFloyd  I need a basic example of viewing a component that usesLazeQueryHook by apolo client from myComponent.jsx in myComponent.stories.js